# Unable to resolve host "get.cm"

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT-P3113). When connecting to a particular Wi-Fi network, I get a message that states: `unable to resolve host "get.cm"`.

I am able to connect to the network and can see other devices on the net, but I cannot connect to websites. All my other PCs on the network function just fine, but this Android tablet cannot get internet access. It works fine on every other network I've accessed.

I have modified the network to use no authentication, WEP, and WPA, but still nothing.

Ideas?

Comment: Any log (`logcat`) that might give a clue? Hard to say otherwise.

Comment: Where do you see that message? Is it in the Wi-Fi settings page, a dialog, a notification, or something else? Also, if you're using Cyanogenmod or another custom ROM, please include that information in the question.

Comment: I am using cyanogenmod 10.1. It's a little notification box that pops up towards the bottom of my homescreen. I also managed to get my hands on a couple android phones, LG spectrum 2 and droid razr m, both right out of the box. Both of these cannot connect to the network either... I'll work on finding a log. But basically it seems to be a problem with android devices not being able to connect, but windows can.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My network was configured to use the network address as the router address. Windows is able to handle this just fine, I guess, but Android systems can not. So I changed the Addressing settings to set the router to end in .161 instead of .160 (the network address) and it's all good :D